# Compare three column pairs and retain occurrences with latest timestamp from fourth column

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data frame, which is a deduced version of my actual date set. Currently, I am shaping the dataset in `tidyverse` and all its sub-packages.

```
set.seed(1111)
productlist <- c("product_1", "product_2")
ITEM <- sample(productlist, 10, replace = TRUE)
QTY <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
TIMESTAMP <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2020-09-09 01:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-09-09 14:00:00"), by="hour"), 10)
REV_DATE <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020-09-07'), as.Date('2020-09-11'), by="day"), 10, replace = TRUE)
DEL_DATE <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020-09-21'), as.Date('2020-09-24'), by="day"), 10, replace = TRUE)
df.orders <- data.frame(ITEM, QTY, TIMESTAMP, REV_DATE, DEL_DATE)
df.orders <- df.orders %>%
  arrange(REV_DATE, DEL_DATE, ITEM) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  select(ID, everything())
```

Thus, the output would look like this.

```
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
| ID |      ITEM | QTY |           TIMESTAMP | REV_DATE   | DEL_DATE   |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | product_1 |   2 | 2020-09-09 11:00:00 | 2020-09-07 | 2020-09-21 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  2 | product_2 |   2 | 2020-09-09 06:00:00 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-21 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  3 | product_2 |   7 | 2020-09-09 05:00:00 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-21 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  4 | product_2 |   1 | 2020-09-09 01:00:00 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-22 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  5 | product_2 |   8 | 2020-09-09 02:00:00 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-24 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  6 | product_2 |   1 | 2020-09-09 13:00:00 | 2020-09-09 | 2020-09-23 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  7 | product_1 |   5 | 2020-09-09 12:00:00 | 2020-09-10 | 2020-09-23 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  8 | product_2 |   7 | 2020-09-09 04:00:00 | 2020-09-10 | 2020-09-23 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  9 | product_2 |   5 | 2020-09-09 09:00:00 | 2020-09-10 | 2020-09-24 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 10 | product_2 |   6 | 2020-09-09 14:00:00 | 2020-09-11 | 2020-09-21 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

My intention is to keep only unique combinations of values in the `ITEM`, `REV_DATE`, and `DEL_DATE` column.

```
df.orders %>%
  group_by(ITEM, DEL_DATE, REV_DATE) %>%
  filter(n()>1)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   ITEM, DEL_DATE, REV_DATE [1]
     ID ITEM        QTY TIMESTAMP           REV_DATE   DEL_DATE  
  <int> <chr>     <int> <dttm>              <date>     <date>    
1     2 product_2     2 2020-09-09 06:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-21
2     3 product_2     7 2020-09-09 05:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-21
```

```
nrow(unique(df.orders[,c("ITEM", "DEL_DATE", "REV_DATE")]))

[1] 9
```

As it can be seen that ID 2 and 3 are identical in terms of `ITEM`, `REV_DATE`, and `DEL_DATE`, whereby `TIMESTAMP` and `QTY` differ. In the original dataset, there are occurrence where I have 5-6 instances where only the
I would like keep only the row with the latest `TIMESTAMP`, in this case ID=2, since the timestamp indicates the most recent version of the occurrence despite the difference in `QTY`. So that the data frame looks like this in the end.

```
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
| ID |      ITEM | QTY |           TIMESTAMP | REV_DATE   | DEL_DATE   |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | product_1 |   2 | 2020-09-09 11:00:00 | 2020-09-07 | 2020-09-21 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  2 | product_2 |   2 | 2020-09-09 06:00:00 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-21 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  3 | product_2 |   1 | 2020-09-09 01:00:00 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-22 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  4 | product_2 |   8 | 2020-09-09 02:00:00 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-24 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  5 | product_2 |   1 | 2020-09-09 13:00:00 | 2020-09-09 | 2020-09-23 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  6 | product_1 |   5 | 2020-09-09 12:00:00 | 2020-09-10 | 2020-09-23 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  7 | product_2 |   7 | 2020-09-09 04:00:00 | 2020-09-10 | 2020-09-23 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  8 | product_2 |   5 | 2020-09-09 09:00:00 | 2020-09-10 | 2020-09-24 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  9 | product_2 |   6 | 2020-09-09 14:00:00 | 2020-09-11 | 2020-09-21 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the row with `max` `TIMESTAMP` for each `ITEM`, `DEL_DATE` and  `REV_DATE`.

```
library(dplyr)

df.orders %>%
  group_by(ITEM, DEL_DATE, REV_DATE) %>%
  slice(which.max(TIMESTAMP))

#     ID ITEM        QTY TIMESTAMP           REV_DATE   DEL_DATE  
#  <int> <chr>     <int> <dttm>              <date>     <date>    
#1     1 product_1     2 2020-09-09 11:00:00 2020-09-07 2020-09-21
#2     7 product_1     5 2020-09-09 12:00:00 2020-09-10 2020-09-23
#3     2 product_2     2 2020-09-09 06:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-21
#4    10 product_2     6 2020-09-09 14:00:00 2020-09-11 2020-09-21
#5     4 product_2     1 2020-09-09 01:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-22
#6     6 product_2     1 2020-09-09 13:00:00 2020-09-09 2020-09-23
#7     8 product_2     7 2020-09-09 04:00:00 2020-09-10 2020-09-23
#8     5 product_2     8 2020-09-09 02:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-24
#9     9 product_2     5 2020-09-09 09:00:00 2020-09-10 2020-09-24
```

If there are cases where there are two or more rows in the group with same `TIMESTAMP` and you want to keep all of them, you can use `filter` in the following way.

```
df.orders %>%
  group_by(ITEM, DEL_DATE, REV_DATE) %>%
  filter(TIMESTAMP == max(TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ronak Shah. After reviewing my dataset, I realised that there are indeed are occasions where timestamps are identical in the same group.

Answer (score 2):

The `distinct` function keeps the first row (the `?distinct` note on `...` reads:

> If there are multiple rows for a given combination of inputs, only the
> first row will be preserved

So if we `arrange` the dataframe with the most recent timestamps at the top and run `distinct` we will preserve the records you want.

```
new_df <- df.orders %>%
  group_by(ITEM, DEL_DATE, REV_DATE) %>%
  arrange(desc(TIMESTAMP)) %>%
  distinct(ITEM, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

```
     ID ITEM        QTY TIMESTAMP           REV_DATE   DEL_DATE  
  <int> <chr>     <int> <dttm>              <date>     <date>    
1    10 product_2     6 2020-09-09 14:00:00 2020-09-11 2020-09-21
2     6 product_2     1 2020-09-09 13:00:00 2020-09-09 2020-09-23
3     7 product_1     5 2020-09-09 12:00:00 2020-09-10 2020-09-23
4     1 product_1     2 2020-09-09 11:00:00 2020-09-07 2020-09-21
5     9 product_2     5 2020-09-09 09:00:00 2020-09-10 2020-09-24
6     2 product_2     2 2020-09-09 06:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-21
7     8 product_2     7 2020-09-09 04:00:00 2020-09-10 2020-09-23
8     5 product_2     8 2020-09-09 02:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-24
9     4 product_2     1 2020-09-09 01:00:00 2020-09-08 2020-09-22
```

Comment: Thanks @TTS. This works fine ! I was aware of there `distinct()` function but I missed the sorting step to retain only the first value.